# How to execute javascript for watir webdriver to change text inside a span id

Tags: javascript, ruby, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I am using Watir Webdriver selenium and trying to run:

```
browser.execute_script($("#CSVFileName").text("template.csv"))
```

I'm trying to execute javascript to change the FileName.csv to template.csv but doesn't appear to be working. Here is the code of the element from the browser.

```
<div class="uploader">
    <div class="load-line" style="width:100%"></div>
    <span class="name" id="CSVFileName">FileName.csv</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to just be missing the quotations around the script - ie `execute_script` expects a string:

```
browser.execute_script('$("#CSVFileName").text("template.csv")')
```